# React js - problem with proxy for web socket link in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, create-react-app, react-apollo

I am setting up the proxy server using setupProxy for my react app using graphql as backend which is running on a different part, doing so The HTTP link proxy is working fine but WebSocket link proxy is giving me an error

For solving the problem I have tried to include options as ws: true, but it's not working.
The error is as follows:
SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '/ws' is invalid.

Error:

[image]

setupProxy.js

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/graphql", { target: "http://localhost:8001/graphql" }));
  app.use(
    proxy("/ws", {
      target: "ws://localhost:8001",
      ws: true,
    })
  );
};
```

index.js

```
import { WebSocketLink } from "apollo-link-ws";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";
//Apollo Imports End

// Declaring constants for GraphQL
const httpLink = new createUploadLink({
  uri: "/graphql"
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: "/ws",
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
});
```

I expected the call should be same as normal call but its throwing an error.

Comment: have you found a solution? I have got the same problem

Comment: Not yet. @Andrew

Comment: Have you tried adding a hostname to your URI when you create the WebSocketLink? i.e. `uri: "localhost/ws"`

Answer (score 2):

`/ws` is not a valid URI for a WebSocket class.
A websocket expect a full URL to connect, you can try it in your browser console:

[image]

In this case, Apollo is using the native web socket class behind the scenes, so if you can make this work, it will work in Apollo too.

Try using `ws://localhost:8001` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace with this

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/graphql", { target: "http://localhost:8001/graphql" }));
  app.use(proxy("ws://locahost:8001"));
};
```

OR

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/graphql", { target: "http://localhost:8001/graphql" }));
  app.use(proxy('/ws', {
   target: 'http://localhost:8001',
   ws: true
  })
 );
};
```

Comment: Sure will check this one and let you know

Comment: Hi @EvilsEmpire, did anyone of the above solution work out?

Comment: What are you putting in for the WebSockLink as shown above?  It requires a full path so how does that match up to '/ws' ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in setupProxy.js file worked for me :

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
  const wsProxy = createProxyMiddleware("/graphql", {
    ws: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    autoRewrite: true,
    target: "http://localhost:8001",
  });
  app.use(wsProxy);
};
```

This is what I have in my apollo-client.ts file

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "/graphql",
  credentials: "include",
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://${window.location.host}/graphql`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    lazy: true,
    connectionParams: {
      headers: {
      //add your headers here
      },
    },
  },
});

const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
);
```